# How can I run mutation onChange, also chain other options?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

Apologies for the newbie question but I'd like to have a boolean field on an edit screen and use the React Switch (https://github.com/markusenglund/react-switch) component to render the switch. Instead of having the form submit button, I want to run the mutation when the switch is changed on the fly. Also, I want to toggle the visibility of sub-options and set their disabled state and change their value based off the state of the "master" switch. My notes are in the code below...

I'm still learning here so this is as far as I've gotten. I've tried googling but I can't seem to find an answer.

Here's a copy of my code but I changed/stripped it down a bit:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Query, Mutation } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Error from "../ErrorMessage";
import Switch from "react-switch";

const MY_ACCOUNT_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    me {
      id
      account {
        toggleOptionOne
        toggleOptionTwo
        toggleOptionThree
      }
    }
  }
`;

const UPDATE_ACCOUNT_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation UPDATE_ACCOUNT_MUTATION(
    $toggleOptionOne: Boolean
    $toggleOptionTwo: Boolean
    $toggleOptionThree: Boolean
  ) {
    updateAccount(
      toggleOptionOne: $toggleOptionOne
      toggleOptionTwo: $toggleOptionTwo
      toggleOptionThree: $toggleOptionThree
    ) {
      toggleOptionOne
      toggleOptionTwo
      toggleOptionThree
    }
  }
`;

class Visibility extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Query query={MY_ACCOUNT_QUERY}>
        {({ data: { me }, loading }) => {
          if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
          if (!me.id) return <p>No user found.</p>;
          return (
            <>
              <VisibilityToggles account={me.account} key={me.account.id} />
            </>
          );
        }}
      </Query>
    );
  }
}

class VisibilityToggles extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    account: PropTypes.shape({
      toggleOptionOne: PropTypes.Boolean,
      toggleOptionTwo: PropTypes.Boolean,
      toggleOptionThree: PropTypes.Boolean
    }).isRequired
  };
  state = {
    toggleOptionOne: this.props.account.toggleOptionOne,
    toggleOptionTwo: this.props.account.toggleOptionTwo,
    toggleOptionThree: this.props.account.toggleOptionThree
  };
  handleChange = (checked, event, id) => {
    this.setState({ [id]: checked });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Mutation
        mutation={UPDATE_ACCOUNT_MUTATION}
        variables={{
          toggleOptionOne: this.state.toggleOptionOne,
          toggleOptionTwo: this.state.toggleOptionTwo,
          toggleOptionThree: this.state.toggleOptionThree
        }}
      >
        {(updateAccount, { loading, error }) => (
          <>
            {error && <Error error={error} />}
            <label htmlFor="toggleOptionOne">
              <Switch
                id="toggleOptionOne"
                name="toggleOptionOne"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                checked={this.state.toggleOptionOne} />
              Master Option Toggle
            </label>
            {/* NOTE: I'd like to run the mutation to save the changed value to the database on the fly without having to have a form submit button */}
            {/* NOTE: toggling above to ON should REVEAL the following 2 items. */}
            {/* Toggling above to OFF should HIDE the following 2 items AND set them to false and disabled. */}
            <fieldset id="THIS_BLOCK_SHOULD_TOGGLE">
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="toggleOptionTwo">
                  <Switch
                    id="toggleOptionTwo"
                    name="toggleOptionTwo"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    checked={this.state.toggleOptionTwo} />
                  Sub Option Toggle 1
                </label>
                {/* NOTE: I'd like to run the mutation to save the changed value to the database on the fly without having to have a form submit button */}
              </div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="toggleOptionThree">
                  <Switch
                    id="toggleOptionThree"
                    name="toggleOptionThree"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    checked={this.state.toggleOptionThree} />
                  Sub Option Toggle 2
                </label>
                {/* NOTE: I'd like to run the mutation to save the changed value to the database on the fly without having to have a form submit button */}
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </>
        )}
      </Mutation>
    );
  }
}

export default Visibility;
```

TLDR: I'd like to do 2 things:
1. run the mutation when the switch is changed
2. When the master switch is changed, either show/hide the sub-options and also enable/disable them and set their value to false if the master switch is false.

Again, apologies if this is a newbie question. I'm still learning :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of ways to achieve what you want. Some might require a bit of restructuring. As it is now, i can advice this:

1) Pass the updateAccount as an argument to the handleChange function and execute it when you think it is the right moment.
2) checkout the refetch property of the Mutation component.

> `refetchQueries`: (mutationResult: FetchResult) => Array<{ query: DocumentNode, variables?: TVariables} | string>

[Mutations Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations/)